# Formatting entire excel worksheet - Python

Tags: python, excel, fonts, format, worksheet

Is there to format the entire xlsx font in python without iterating through each cell. And if this is possible , which module perform this?

Answer (score 0):

You should try [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/). It is very easy to use.
There is this [cheat sheet](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/pybokeh/jupyter_notebooks/blob/master/xlwings/Excel_Formatting.ipynb) that can help you with the library.

I think a line of code like this is close to what you need:

```
Range('A1:Z100').api.Font.Size = 20
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can read xls files with the help of python module `xlrd` to install it use the command.

```
pip install xlrd
```

Below is the example of how to use xlrd to open spreadsheet in python.

```
import xlrd
file_location = "your excel spreadsheet file location"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

# for printing it row by row
for col in range(sheet.ncols):
    print(sheet.cell_value(0, col)) # change 0 to print different rows
```

For further reading check the [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-python-parse-spreadsheet-data/) please & for the video guidance click [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p0DNcTnreuY)

I hope it works for you : D